# Using nmap responsibly towards learning and understanding the restrictions to safeguard myself?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, nmap

I hope this thread doesn't get yanked to fast and if you have any negative feedback for me in asking this question please take it easy on me as I'm just a beginner trying to learn more in the most responsible way possible.

I installed Kali Linux awhile back and i've been using it on a private network some of us students built at our university. The network is specifically setup to allow us to do things freely without raising flags from our local IT department so we can learn about network security and of course "have some fun". The more and more I mess around inside Kali's OS and use the tools that are available to me the more interesting it becomes and the more tempted I want to try stuff on other public networks for learning purposes.

I would just like to know if using network scanning tools, like nmap, at a local coffee shop network or public network is illegal or not and if using it on my home network is illegal as well. I would like to test tools like nmap and others against other networks and would like to know the restrictions and dangers I should be aware of.

Comment: What you do on your home network is your own business and no one would know what you are doing as long as the traffic doesn't go out through the Internet.  You can always "air gap" or not connect your network physically to your cable/DSL modem.  If you have several PCs (better if they could run a VM or two), you could create an isolated network or two for testing at your home.  This question has a couple of problems for here IMHO: 1) it's rather open ended 2) it's seeking legal advice.

Comment: http://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that it depends, but in general I'd strongly recommend against running active security scanning tools (e.g. nmap) on any network that you either do not own, or have specific explicit permission from the owner to run against.

The main factor will be what country you are in.  Most countries have legislation that gets applied (badly in a lot of cases) to computer crime/hacking etc. Port scanning (e.g. nmap) can be seen as hacking and therefore could be in breach of those laws.

Unfortunately many of the laws I've seen are unclear on what exactly is and is not legal with regards to testing tools, so if your scanning is detected you could well be arrested even if it's not 100% clear that what you're doing is illegal.

If you're looking to practice tools and techniques then look for things like [CTF tournaments](https://ctftime.org/) or test systems that are designed to be scanned (e.g. https://www.pentesterlab.com/)